# Spark kafka avro producer in structured streaming

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, avro

I have a working UDF that does a side effect, send a kafka message in avro, which I know is not the purpose of a UDF. I could not find a good way to accomplish this, and this works... but I'm wondering if this is a really bad idea. Does someone have a better way of doing this?

```
#if you don't have a schema reg
var testSchema = "{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"myrecord\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"f1\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}"
    val df = Seq(
      ("1")
    ).toDF("f1")

    val topic = "mytest"
    val brokers = "kafka01:9092"
    val schemaRegistryURL = "http://sr:8081"
    val subjectValueName = topic + "-value"

    val KafkaAvroProducerFunct: (String => String) = (value: String) => {
      val props = new Properties()
      props.put("bootstrap.servers", brokers)
      props.put("key.serializer", classOf[KafkaAvroSerializer].getCanonicalName)
      props.put("value.serializer", classOf[KafkaAvroSerializer].getCanonicalName)
      props.put("schema.registry.url", schemaRegistryURL)
      val producer = new KafkaProducer[GenericRecord, GenericRecord](props)
      val vProps = new kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties(props)
      val avro_schema = new RestService(schemaRegistryURL).getLatestVersion(subjectValueName)
      val messageSchema = new Schema.Parser().parse(avro_schema.getSchema)
      val avroRecord = new GenericData.Record(messageSchema)
      avroRecord.put("f1", value)
      //val record = new ProducerRecord(topic, "key", avroRecord)
      val record = new ProducerRecord[GenericRecord, GenericRecord](topic, avroRecord)
      producer.send(record)
      "sent"
    }
```

Comment: can you add a bit more on what you are trying to do?

Comment: the use case is to create a avro kafka message per row of a dataframe on streaming. I have looked at serializing using udf abd then using sinks... it's not so easy to get working correctly.. while doing the above udf is very straight forward.

Comment: the above code works for a simple single column message.. but breaks when you add complexity.